# Flags with border on hover

Tags: html, css

Hello I have 3 flags (Italian, german, english) with the purpose to change language for the whole site in future. How can I make a border on a hover effect that could alxo work with IE ?

this is the CCS

```
.miniflags {
    float:right
    margin : 5px 20px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

and here the HTML

```
<div id="bandiere">
    <a><img src="ita.png" class="miniflags" /></a>
    <a><img src="ger.png" class="miniflags" /></a>
    <a><img src="eng.png" class="miniflags" /></a>
</div>
```

Thanx for help

Alex

Comment: Completely unrelated to my comment below on :focus and :hover, using flags for language is a bad idea. Austrian and luxembourg people aren't german, the swiss minority speaking italian isn't italian and obviously US citizens, australians, ... speak english too. You'd better write "italiano - deutsch - english" (with the correct lang and hreflang attributes) and place it somewhere in your header. It's less visual but people are accustomed to it. There is no such thing as THE solution for languages, sad thing, so there are plenty of solutions but flags are far from being the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
.miniflags img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

or

```
.miniflags a:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

to your css

i believe the 2nd will work better (a:hover)

Answer (score 2):

<s>If you apply the `miniflags` class to the `<a>` instead, the `:hover` pseudoselector will work.</s>

The `miniflags` class hardly seems necessary. Just remember that `:hover` works only for links in older versions of IE, so you will need to apply it to the `<a>` tags instead of the `<img>`.

```
<div id="bandiere">
    <a><img src="ita.png" /></a>
    <a><img src="ger.png" /></a>
    <a><img src="eng.png" /></a>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    #bandiere img {
        float:right
        margin : 5px 20px;
        padding-right:10px;
    }

    #bandiere a:hover, #bandiere a:focus {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanx very helpull and easy !

Comment: The first version works with the .miniflags class; the last version  without the class moves all the DIV id=bandiere

Comment: Ahh. If `.miniflags` appears in other locations, then you'll need to reapply it. But the `#bandiere a:hover` rule should still stand, unless you need to apply it to *links* outside of this particular div, as well.

Comment: Many people use the mouse, some (must) use a keyboard: for each CSS rule with a :hover selector, you should always add the same selector with :focus instead of :hover, that is: "#bandiere a:hover, #bandiere a:focus { /* */ }

Comment: @Felipe Alsacreations: True! Edited.

Answer (score 1):

IE (until 6 IIRC) only allows hover for links. So you'd have to add the `:hover` to the `a` not to the image. The `<a>` must have a `href` attribute for this to work of course.